# The weather is cloud fast bowler is very dangerous. what is the reasons?

Tags: cricket

The weather is cloud patch is helping for fast bowler ball is seem spin and bounce .these ball is very deficit to batsman  playing short. what is the reasons` .

Comment: Hi, welcome to Sports.SE.  Are you asking why a fast bowler has an advantage during cloudy weather?

Comment: g why first bowler adventage during cloud weather

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There have been a number of scientific papers on this subject, for example Binnie<sup>1</sup>:

> The suggestion is made that the observed increase in the swing under conditions of high humidity is caused by condensation shock. The moisture in the rapidly expanding air close to the ball does not condense when the saturation limit is reached but continues in an unstable, supersaturated state until violent condensation occurs, probably at the lowest pressure attained. This condensation shock assists the seam in upsetting the laminar boundary-layer. Calculations show that this effect can occur only when the relative humidity in the ambient air is nearly 100%.

and James, MacDonald and Hart<sup>2</sup>:

> It is clear that humidity remains a perplexing issue with regards to cricket ball swing. Similar to many previous authors, this study shows that there is no direct, nor indirect manner in which humidity can significantly affect the ability of a bowler to make the ball swing. It is therefore logical to conclude that humidity may not have the significant influence on swing bowling that is widely assumed. Throughout the scientific literature on this topic, the issue of humidity is repeatedly discussed; however, it is proposed that this is an error, and that the cricketing community is not nearly as fixated on humidity as has been reported. The authors of this study have been privy to numerous discussions with various world class cricket players on this topic including England’s Andrew Flintoff. It is apparent that contrary to what is debated in the scientific literature, these players believe that cloud cover is the atmospheric condition of primary concern, not humidity. Players are convinced that the ball swings more on cloudy, overcast days and whilst the humidity levels on these days may tend to be higher than normal, humidity is not the key factor.

References:

1. [Binnie, A.M. (1976) The effect of humidity on the ‘swing’ of cricket balls *International Journal of Mechanical Sciences*, Volume 18, Issues 9-10, 497-499](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020740376900461)
2. [David James, Danielle C. MacDonald, John Hart (2012) The effect of atmospheric conditions on the swing of a cricket ball *Procedia Engineering*, Volume 34, 188-193](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877705812016463)

Other links:

- https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/How-do-overcast-conditions-help-a-fast-bowler-swing-the-ball/articleshow/205837.cms
- https://engineeringsport.co.uk/2012/06/14/humidity-doesnt-affect-cricket-ball-swing/